# why we use Prototype in Object oriented programming in JS

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

i am a newbie to Js OOp.
I was reading somewhere that Prototypes are used in `OOP` in `JS`
Ok here is an example

```
function Dog(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.bark = function() {
        console.log("Woof");
    }
}
```

Now my question is why can't we just create objects like this

```
Dog doberman = new Dog;
```

This creates a new Dog object.

But through prototypes we do something like this

```
var doberman = Object.create(dog);
```

I read that the functions can be separated and through prototype they can be added to the object.
**Please help me. I am confused..**

Well the question simply is
**Why use Object.prototype for methods?**

Comment: Prototype allow you to assure that any object of that class will have (at least initially) that property (i.e. variable, method).

Comment: JavaScript is not typed so you can't use `Dog doberman = new Dog()` but you most certainly can use `var doberman = new Dog()`

Comment: For `Object.create`, I suggest you read the docs ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: It's OK to hit the space bar when you're programming in JavaScript.

Comment: *Note* prototypes can also help with separating methods of an object, such that they are not recreated with each instance.

Comment: I suggest to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript and https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek hey thanks can you please tell me how to create an object with a prototype which contains methods?

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini Sure, here is an [example with the `bark` method](http://jsfiddle.net/5veucgqq/). You would just do `objectName.prototype.method = function(){ ... }` in general.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek ok but i i create say 20 objects from a constructor function and have another function say bark then i have to do object.prototype.method for all those 20 methods right?

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini The prototype is attached to the "class" in this case, you don't need to redo it for each instance.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek answer me (i mena not comment) and i will accept it.. thanks

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini Actually since this was marked as a duplicate it cannot accept any more answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Now my question is why can't we just create objects like this: `Dog dog = new Dog;`

You can, actually. Your `Dog` function also serves as a "constructor-function", like so:

```
var doberman = new Dog( "Fenton" );
```

I appreciate this is confusing because JavaScript offers many different ways of doing (essentially) the same thing, for example:

```
var doberman = { name: "Fenton", age: 5, bark: function() { return "woof"; } }
```

(though my first example creates a new `object` instance that uses `Dog` as a prototype (a kind of inheritance), whereas my second example creates a new `object` instance with only instance-level properties that are not inherited, though thanks to JavaScript's duck-typing there are very few times where the difference matters (though in high-performance JavaScript always prefer prototype constructors over instance-level properties).

Comment: You mean We can also do OOP in Js ithout prototypes?? Well it will effect performance right cause as they are not recreated with every instance??

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini Yes you can, although using prototypes on methods can save you memory for each instance. If you don't have too many instances simply not using a prototype would not affect you very much.